# What is the right way to convert into UNIX timestamp from the date and time in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a lot of dates with time in this format:

```
day.mon.year - hour:min:sec
```

And I need to convert this dates with time into Unix timestamp.

I used [tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) structure, but I can't fill those fields:

```
tm_wday
tm_yday
```

And I don't must I fill those field, because I don't know do this field have any effect to the value of Unix timestamp.

Help me to choose rigth way to calculate Unix timestamp.

P.S. Dates with time aren't current, they can be date of the 20-th century or future dates (to 2038 year).

P.P.S. I use OS Windows.

Comment: WTF. Close-mongers, **please GTFO and go back to trolling Wikipedia for deletion**! This is a perfectly valid question. Note to mods: can we get a feature whereby users who regularly abuse the vote-to-close feature get their vote-to-close privileges suspended or permanently revoked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX has a formula for exactly what you want:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

```
tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

This works whenever you have a broken-down time in GMT, even if the underlying system's `mktime`, etc. functions do not use the same format `time_t` as "Unix timestamps".

If your original time is in local time, you can use `mktime` and `gmtime` to convert it to GMT using the system's notion of timezone rules. If you want to apply your own timezone offset rules, just do that manually before using the above formula.

Comment: So do Daylight saving time variable do not needed to calculate Unix time?

Comment: Like I said, the formula requires input in GMT. DST is part of converting local time to GMT.

Comment: How do I handle times before October 1582?

Comment: @Aaron: That's a completely different question (ask it as a new one if you like) and depends on what time system you want to interpret them in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on unix, mktime() will get the second part of the timestamp. It ignores the tm_wday and tm_yday fields.

Comment: Ignoring those fields is not unix-dependent. It's required by ISO C.